# Redis: Sort and get n Neighbour Keys

Tags: redis

Let's say I have these pairs in Redis:

```
1237.56 "John"
1224.59 "Robert"
1213.34 "Mahmoud"
1242.90 "George"
1020.11 "Mary"
1723.09 "Jay"
1589.77 "Khan"
1106.62 "Albert"
```

The keys are always a decimal number. When provided a number, I would like to get two keys in both directions with closest number.

For example, if I search for the neighbours of `1242`, the resultset should have:

```
1224.59 "Robert"
1237.56 "John"
1242.90 "George"
1589.77 "Khan"
```

Is this possible? I'm still new to Redis and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no the same time.

**Why yes?** The only one redis data type - [SORTED SET](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) allow you to get range of values based on decimal. So with [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) you can get values by score range.

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE theKey 1220 1600
```

Gives you sought-for data set.

**Why No?** In your question your ask about neighbours of score. ZRANGEBYSCORE can get values from min score to max score but not the "get X values less then given" or "X values great then given".

Answer (score 1):

This *is* possible using `zrangebyscore` with the limit parameter. You will need to make two queries - one to get the neighbours on each side.

For example if you want to get the `n` with a score less than `score` the query looks like this:

```
zrangebyscore KEY <SCORE> +inf limit 0 <N>
```

And the `n` with scores greater than like this:

```
zrevrangebyscore KEY +inf <SCORE> limit 0 <N>
```

---

Say you had sorted set `test:key_sort` like this:

```
"a": 10
"b": 20
"c": 30
"d": 40
"e": 50
```

Then `zrevrangebyscore test:key_sort +inf 25 limit 0 2` returns `d, c` and `zrangebyscore test:key_sort -inf 25 limit 0 2` returns `a, b`

Comment: Any idea on performance for this type of approach? For instance if I just want the 'closest' neighbors (one below and one above) and my dataset is large (millions).

Comment: redis says the perf is O(logN) https://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore