# Is there an equivalent to the python bisect command in redis?

Tags: redis

I am a fan of python's bisect functions which I use, for instance, to get the item in a list *closest* (in my case on the left) to another item I have.

Does this exist in redis? I do not know redis terminology very well.

For instance:

```
li = [1,2,5,6,10,15,19,20]
itm = 12

the closest value on the left to 12 would be: 10
```

Comment: I know, but they might use a different term than 'bisect'.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is nothing in the [command documentation](http://redis.io/commands) indicating that such a function exists natively in Redis.

You can execute [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) scripts with [EVAL and friends](http://redis.io/commands/eval), so if you find or write a Lua script that performs this function you can load and execute it.

Comment: I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273371/redis-sort-and-get-n-neighbour-keys# I guess that comes closest, right?

Comment: The semantics are completely different. It is not going to give you the closest item in the list, it's going to give you the items that fall within a range of values. If you don't know how far away a given item is from the one you are testing against, you might get multiple items back or none at all.